# Fancybox navigation inside galleries not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have the following thumbnails gallery:

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a class="fancybox" href="img/projects/glob/1.jpg" rel="gallery1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/projects/glob/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a class="fancybox" href="img/projects/glob/2.jpg" rel="gallery1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/projects/glob/thumb2.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a class="fancybox" href="img/projects/glob/3.png" rel="gallery1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/projects/glob/thumb3.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a class="fancybox" href="img/projects/glob/4.png" rel="gallery1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/projects/glob/thumb4.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 3vh">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a class="fancybox" href="img/projects/glob/5.png" rel="gallery1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/projects/glob/thumb5.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a class="fancybox" href="img/projects/glob/6.png" rel="gallery1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/projects/glob/thumb6.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a class="fancybox" href="img/projects/glob/7.png" rel="gallery1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/projects/glob/thumb7.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a class="fancybox" href="img/projects/glob/8.png" rel="gallery1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/projects/glob/thumb8.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 3vh">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a class="fancybox" href="img/projects/glob/9.png" rel="gallery1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/projects/glob/thumb9.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, navigation arrows are showing properly:
[image: Arrow showing correctly]

But, once I click on the arrow, I see only a blank picture:
[image: blank picture after clicking on the arrow]

The fancybox function is in a .js file...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

...which is loaded in the head of the page:

```
<script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Possibly, could you create a `jsfiddle` for this?

Comment: I'm trying, but fancybox is not working in jsfiddle :/

Comment: Just save the `fiddle` link at however stage you have.. I'll look into it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sbrg3m6z/

Comment: Which version of `fancybox` you are using?? because as per **[this version i.e. `v2.1.5`](http://www.surrealcms.com/tuts/how-to-edit-a-fancybox-gallery)** you have to use `data-fancybox-group` instead of `rel` to group the images as `gallery`

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.4. I've tested with "data-fancybox-group" instead of "rel" but now the arrows have dissapeared.

Comment: Don't use it unless you are having `v2.1.5` as I said before.. Even I am not getting why this weired behavior.. It should work as per their docs..